# Get parent element from facebook iframe like button

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, iframe, facebook-javascript-sdk

**UPDATE**
I'm trying to get the parent element from within the facebook like button.

The reason I need this is because I'm building a facebook app for Christmas where the users click the mascot they like and it gives an animation from the mascot and a like to our page. Each mascot has it own like button and this is the reason I need to know the parent from the clicked like button to know which mascot to animate.

I've tried to add a click event directly to `div.figure` but the like button stays on top of everything and the click isn't called.

So far, I've tried this

HTML & PHP

```
<!-- The JQuery version I'm using -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- The parent element where the like button iframe is called -->
<div class="fb-like figure" val="1" style="background-color: red; padding: 2px;" data-href="https://facebook.com/OptimizingConcepts" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>

<!-- The element where I want to update the value -->
<div id="val_1" val="<?php echo $data[0]['figure_1']; ?>"><?php echo intval(($total/100)+$data[0]['figure_1']); ?></div>
```

Javascript SDK

```
FB.init({appId: 'my_app_id', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
        var id = $(this).parent('.figure', window.parent.document).attr('val'),
            val = $('#val_'+id, window.parent.document).attr('val');
            alert('ID: '+id+'VAL: '+val);
        $('#val_'+id).text((total/100)*val);
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function (targetUrl) {
        alert('You just UNliked ');
    });
};
```

The problem is that the values always come 'undefined'

Comment: What dou you mean by _from “within” the iframe_? You can not access the DOM of the iframe at all, because it’s from another domain. And what problem do you _actually_ want to solve here?

Comment: Hi @CBroe I've updated da Question, thank you